# Extend Marshmallow Schema but Override Field Required Property

Tags: python, inheritance, marshmallow

Noob question, but I have a simple schema:

```
class User(Schema):
    name = fields.Str(required=True)
    email = fields.Str(required=True)
```

And I want to extend it, but in the extended case make a field optional

```
class UserIHavePhoneNumberFor(User):
    phone = fields.Str(required=True)
    # Don't Care about Email because I can pester them via phone!
```

I've checked the docs but can't find a way to do this.
Any help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably not in the docs because these are just basic class inheritance rules in python.

```py
class UserIHavePhoneNumberFor(User):
    phone = fields.Str(required=True)
    email = fields.Str(required=False)
```

If you need more complex rules than that, you can always just write your own custom validation rules:

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html#raising-errors-in-pre-post-processor-methods

or even:

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/extending.html#schema-level-validation

It's usually best to try and see if you can avoid using those first by being smart about declaring your fields, but it's there when you need it.

Answer (score -1):

Is partial loading you are looking for?

Skipping `required=True` validaton

https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#partial-loading